# TeXstudio and MiKTeX on Windows 10 Annoying Package Manager notification

Tags: compiling, windows

I just hope anyone here has resolved an issue with MiKTeX on Windows 10 during editing using TeXstudio.

The application is constantly popping out notification warning messages about installation of packages by the package manager. The pop out windows appears so frequently that severely interferes the user works.

Can this be modified so to have the App install packages in the background without interruption of the user?

Comment: This happens, I suppose, when you launch the compilation?

Comment: @KJO..   ok but which of the 2 is best ?

Comment: it would be quite unusual to get this frequently unless you are constantly adding new, not installed packages to your document or for some reason the installation constantly fails.

Comment: that's nothing TeXstudio is responsible for, but MiKTeX. you should check in the Settings, if the option "always install missing packages on-the-fly" is checked. adjust to your preferences. I recommend to install all packages on your local system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an illustration of the setting needs to be adjusted in order to avoid the notifications.

[image]

Comment: I would assume that it also works with _Always install missing packages on-the-fly_? That might make more sense since the packages seem to be required to compile your documents. Subsequent compilations will go faster since the packages only need to be installed once.

Comment: Where to find the MikTex console in Windows 10? I have installed both MikTex and Texstudio and both work finely but I cannot locate the file given in the figure above.